# place picture under picture

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to place picture under picture in a `FrameLayout` or `LinearLayout`, so when I take pictures with my camera the pictures shall be placed under each other.

The problem is, that I am able to add only one picture. There appear the following error for the second one:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=131074, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.unitnode/com.unitnode.OpenprojectAlternative}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

Here is my layoutfile:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/openproctScrollview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:padding="15dp">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/pictureTabLinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/neuesBildButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/addtabbutton" />
    </FrameLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

For this I first create a new Object for the `ImageView`with: `imageView = new ImageView(this.getActivity())`; and set this: `imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);`

And with this I set the Image to the `ImageView`, set the height and add the `ImageView` to the Layout:

```
imageView.setMaxHeight(createScaleBitmap.getHeight());
Log.d("bmRotated.getHeight()", "bmRotated.getHeight() " + createScaleBitmap.getHeight());
imageView.setImageBitmap(createScaleBitmap);

FrameLayout.LayoutParams viewParameters = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
viewGroup.addView(imageView, viewParameters);
```

EDIT: I tried it with creating a new `LinearLayout` each time. But the result is the same (I even can't add one picture anymore):

> layout = new LinearLayout(this.getActivity());

```
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        layout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

        viewGroup.addView(layout);
        layout.addView(imageView);
```

where `viewGroup` is the `LinearLayout`

Comment: Which `View` are you adding the imageView to? Both `FrameLayout` and `ScrollView` should only contain *one* child view (the child view can contain more views however).

Comment: To the `FrameLayout`. Which Layout supports more than one child or are there any other possibilities?

Comment: There are many, `LinearLayout` and `RelativeLayout` are two. What it seems you want to do is to have a `LinearLayout` directly inside the `ScrollView`, and then add your created `ImageView`s to that layout. From your example it looks like you are creating a new layout everytime and adds that.

Answer (score 0):

You have added only one framelayout.
"Number of framelayout=number of Pictures to store."
So When you want to store the picture attach to the frame and make it invisible and make the other frame visible and then run the intent again.
Query me for further help.

Comment: I tried it with creating new `LinearLayouts` each time (see my Edit). Is this attempt correct?

Comment: Dont know weather this is correct I haven't tried but please try making less layouts as this will be stress the UI thread. Try either of the two stuffs 1. Use Dynamic Fragment or 2. Use two FrameLAyout.

Answer (score 0):

If you add multiple images to a `FrameLayout` they will be effectively stacked and you'll only see the image at the top of the stack.

Is this what you want?

If you want to show them one after another and scroll through them (as you're using a `ScrollView`) then you should consider using a `GridView` or a `ListView` and add the images to an adapter.